Check my derivation please - MLE for a gaussian with $\theta = \mu = \sigma^2 >0$
I was tasked with the following: 
Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, random i.i.d. samples where $\mu = \sigma^2 = \theta > 0$ and $\theta$ is an unknown parameter.

lets find the MLE, we'll use the log-likelihood we found in the lecture, with
$$R_n^2 \triangleq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X}_n)^2$$
$$l_n(\mu,\sigma) = \frac{-n}{2} \left[\log(\sigma^2)+ \frac{R_n^2}{\sigma^2} + \frac{(\bar{X_n} -\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\right]$$
$$l_n(\theta) = \frac{-n}{2}\left[\log(\theta) + \frac{R_n^2}{\theta} + \frac{(\bar{X_n}-\theta)^2}{\theta}\right]$$
$$\partial_{\theta}l_n(\theta)=0 = \frac{1}{\theta} - \frac{R_n^2}{\theta^2} + \frac{\theta \cdot (-2)(\bar X_n - \theta) - (\bar X_n - \theta)^2 \cdot 1}{\theta^2}$$
$$\begin{aligned}0 &= \theta - R_n^2 - [ \theta \cdot (2)(\bar X_n - \theta) + (\bar X_n - \theta)^2] \\ 0 &=\theta - R_n^2 -[(\bar X_n -\theta)(2\theta + \bar X_n - \theta)] \\ 0 &=\theta -R_n^2 - [\bar X_n^2 - \theta^2] \\ \theta &= \frac{-1+ \sqrt{1 + 4 (R_n^2+X_n^2)}}{2}\end{aligned}$$
we're taking the positive one because $\theta>0$. 
is this correct? it looks a little odd... next I'm to find the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}$ using the delta method - this function doesn't look too nice so I want to know if I'm on the right track. If I am can I get a hint about how to proceed?


You should define $R_n^2$ but end up with $\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{\frac{4 \sum _{i=1}^n x_i^2}{n}+1}-1\right)$ as the maximum likelihood estimator.

I defined R_n but i don't see how that gets me an equivalent expression to yours.

Because $R_n^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X_n})^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2-\bar{X}_n^2$, then $R_n^2+\bar{X}n^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum{i=1}^n X_i^2$ which matches my comment.  So I agree with your result (except I would label the result $\hat{\theta}$).

can you please show me why you can take $\bar{X}_n$ out of the brackets like that?

Expand $(X_i-\bar{X_n})^2$.
